# Delete Multiple Records Using Checkboxes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm beginner in rails.

I don't know how delete mutiple records using checkboxes in Rails,
if line_item belonged to a cart.

cart.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cart
```

views/carts/show.html.erb

```
<%= @cart.line_items.each do |item| %>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "item_ids[]", item.id %></td>
<% end %>

<%= button_to "Delete selected", {action: "destroy_multiple", id: @cart}, method: :delete%>
```

carts_controller.rb

```
  def destroy_multiple
    @cart.destroy_line_item(params[:item_ids])
    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { redirect_to cart_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

cart.rb

```
def destroy_line_item(items)
    items.errors.empty?
    ids = items.split(",")
    ids.each do |id|
        line_items.destroy(LineItem.find(id))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [delete_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001800) or [destroy_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799)

```
def destroy_multiple
  LineItem.delete_all(:id => params[:item_ids])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply Try

```
def destroy_multiple
  @cart.line_items.where(id: params[:item_ids]).destroy_all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to cart_url }
     format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank for your comment ! I edited it. But wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)....

Answer (score 0):

my blog app

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IF3xNRkPLSAHc-cD3I2sH3tYkb9WADeu

Rails 5 - Delete Multiple Records Using Checkboxes

articles/index.html.erb

```
...
<%= form_tag destroy_selected_path, method: :delete,remote: true do %>
<table>
...
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
<tr>
<td><%= check_box_tag "blog_articles[]", article.id %></td>
<td><%= article.title %></td>
........
</table>
<%= submit_tag 'Delete selected' %>
<% end %>
```

articles_controller.rb

```
...
def destroy
if params[:blog_articles]
Article.destroy(params[:blog_articles])
else
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article.destroy
end
redirect_to articles_path
end
...
```

routes.rb

```
...
resources :articles do
    resources :comments
end
get '/articles/destroy_selected', to: 'articles#destroy_selected', as: 
:destroy_selected
....
```